# Jenkins pass build parameters to email-ext template

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jelly, email-ext

How can I pass the build parameters to the email-ext jelly template?
Before making some builds I would like to put a different custom message/some announcement/non-code changes, decisions etc. I'm thinking of putting this as a build parameter so that I'm presented with a screen prompting me to enter the message if I'm going to build manually.

Edit: I found a solution, the build params are available as Env variables, I have this code to access Env variables:

```
   <j:set var="buildenv" value="${build.getEnvironment(listener)}"/>
   <j:set var="customMsg" value="${buildenv.get('customMsg')}"/>
   ${customMsg}
```

Comment: If you found a solution, create a new answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Switch to the email-ext groovy email templates.

Then, copy the sample [`groovy-html.template`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template) and customize it by adding the following script -

```
<%
  def parametersAction = build.getAction(ParametersAction.class)

  if (parametersAction != null)
  {
    for (p in parametersAction.parameters)
    {
      %><%=p.name%>=<%=p.value%><br/><%
    }                                               
  }
%>
```

Take a look at the [`hudson.model.ParametersAction`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParametersAction.html) class.

Comment: Thanks: I found a different way, the build params are available as Env variables, I have this code to access Env variables:            '<j:set var="buildenv" value="${build.getEnvironment(listener)}"/>
           <j:set var="customMsg" value="${buildenv.get('customMsg')}"/>
           ${customMsg}'

Answer (score 2):

The only what worked for me in my email template is:

```
<%
    import hudson.model.*

    def YOUR_VARIABLE= build.getEnvVars()["SOME_BUILD_PARAMETER"];
%>
```

Then you can use

```
${YOUR_VARIABLE}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked for me for variables defined inside my pipeline script was the accepted answer of this question:

[Access variable in email ext template using Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884904/access-variable-in-email-ext-template-using-jenkins-pipeline)

I added a answer that variables needed to be defined like

```
env.MY_VARIABLE="Some value"
```

inside the pipeline script.